# Can static methods in Python access/modify class variables?

Tags: python, class, static, static-methods

I am learning Python and reading about classmethods and staticmethods. I came across this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/ which says "A static method can’t access or modify class state." This looks wrong and misleading to me when I tested this small piece of code

```
class AB:
    x = 5
    @classmethod
    def mymethod1(cls):
        AB.x = AB.x+1
        print("Value of x is ",AB.x)
    @staticmethod
    def mymethod2():
        AB.x = AB.x + 1
        print("Value of x is ", AB.x)

c = AB()
c.mymethod1()
c.mymethod2()
```

As can be seen from the above, the staticmethod named mymethod2 can access and modify the variable X. So so is the statement actually wrong (A static method can’t access or modify class state.) or am I missing something.

Comment: What happens if you have a subclass? A classmethod defined on the parent class can still modify the subclass's class variables(if you do `cls.x`), but the staticmethod can't. (I do agree that that the statement is poorly worded)

Comment: Thanks got it now, a poorly worded and confusing statement!!